# Effectively order XYZ coordinates from many huge CSV files into small tiles

Tags: python, csv, coordinates, bigdata

**My problem and goal**:

I have many huge (1-10GB) CSV files which contains billions of XYZ coordinates. I need to interpolate them into regular grids, reasonably effectively (not taking weeks of computing on supercomputer).

**My approach:**

When working with few smaller files I load all into one Pandas dataframe:

```
file_names = [files for files in os.listdir(my_path) if files.endswith(".csv")]  
data_list = []
for file_name in file_names:    
  df = pd.read_csv(my_path + "\\" + file_name, header=None, names=["x","y","z"], dtype=np.float32)
  data_list.append(df)    
frame = pd.concat(data_list)
```

After that I get with frame[x].min() etc. min/max of coordinates and calculates extent of tiles I want to break the data into to ease the interpolation:

```
tile_extents = [min_x - (min_x%tile_size), max_x - (max_x%tile_size) + tile_size, min_y - (min_y%tile_size), max_y - (max_y%tile_size) + tile_size]
for i in range(int((tile_extents[1]-tile_extents[0])/tile_size)):
  for j in range(int((tile_extents[3]-tile_extents[2])/tile_size)):
    current_tile_extent = [tile_extents[0]+i*tile_size, tile_extents[0]+i*tile_size+tile_size, tile_extents[2]+j*tile_size, tile_extents[2]+j*tile_size+tile_size]
    current_frame = frame[(frame["x"]>current_tile_extent[0]) & (frame["x"]<current_tile_extent[1]) & (frame["y"]>current_tile_extent[2]) & (frame["y"]<current_tile_extent[3])]
```

I can save that into CSV files and run the interpolation on these small subsets afterwards. **But what should I do if I have 100GB or more of XYZ coordinates? How to order it so I can save them into tiles?**

Comment: Do you found solution to your removed [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36638598/how-to-read-both-header-and-from-specific-line-with-pandas-read-csv)?

Comment: @jezrael yes, thank you, I realized after better search it is duplicate and it is already answered here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[pandas.read_csv()](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html) can work in chunks (see `chunksize` parameter).

The following code first reads all files to find the min and max values of `x` and `y`, then computes the tiles and creates a file for each tile (`tiles\i,j.csv`). Then, it reads all files again, this time writing the rows into the appropriate tile files.
Be sure to adjust the `chunksize` to your needs!

I tested this with some fake data, and it looks good:

```
import os
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

def get_df_in_chunks(file_names, **kwargs):
    """Read all files in chunks."""
    # Set default chunk size if not specified.
    kwargs['chunksize'] = kwargs.get('chunksize', 100000)
    for file_name in file_names:
        df = pd.read_csv(file_name, **kwargs)
        yield from iter(df)

my_path = '.'
file_names = [my_path + "\\" + file for file in os.listdir(my_path) if file.endswith(".csv")]
print('file_names: {}'.format(file_names))

# Read all files to determine the global min and max values.
min_x = +np.inf
max_x = -np.inf
min_y = +np.inf
max_y = -np.inf
for chunk in get_df_in_chunks(file_names, header=None, dtype=np.float32,
                              usecols=["x","y"], names=["x","y"]):
    print('  - chunk: {}'.format(chunk.shape))
    min_x = min(min_x, chunk["x"].min())
    max_x = max(max_x, chunk["x"].max())
    min_y = min(min_y, chunk["y"].min())
    max_y = max(max_y, chunk["y"].max())
print("x min/max:", min_x, max_x)
print("y min/max:", min_y, max_y)

# Calculate tile extents.
tile_size = 1.5
tile_limits = [min_x - (min_x%tile_size),
               max_x - (max_x%tile_size) + tile_size,
               min_y - (min_y%tile_size),
               max_y - (max_y%tile_size) + tile_size]
print("tile_size:", tile_size)
print("tile_limits:", tile_limits)

if not os.path.exists(my_path + "\\tiles"):
    os.mkdir(my_path + "\\tiles")

tile_files = []
try:
    # Open all tile files.
    for i in range(int(round(tile_limits[1]-tile_limits[0])/tile_size)):
        for j in range(int(round(tile_limits[3]-tile_limits[2])/tile_size)):
            tile_extent = [tile_limits[0] + i*tile_size,
                           tile_limits[0] + i*tile_size + tile_size,
                           tile_limits[2] + j*tile_size,
                           tile_limits[2] + j*tile_size + tile_size]
            f = open(my_path + "\\tiles\\{},{}.csv".format(i,j), 'w')
            tile_files.append((f, tile_extent))

    for chunk in get_df_in_chunks(file_names, header=None, dtype=np.float32,
                                  usecols=["x","y","z"], names=["x","y","z"]):
        # For each tile, write all relevant rows into the corresponding tile file.
        for f, tile_extent in tile_files:
            # Option 1: boolean condition.
            frame = chunk[(chunk["x"] >= tile_extent[0]) &
                          (chunk["x"] <  tile_extent[1]) &
                          (chunk["y"] >= tile_extent[2]) &
                          (chunk["y"] <  tile_extent[3])]
            # Option 2: query using numexpr. Could be faster, but wasn't in my test.
            #frame = chunk.query('x >= {} & x < {} & y >= {} & y < {}'.format(*tile_extent))

            ##print('file: {} tile_extent: {} frame: shape={}'.format(f.name, tile_extent, frame.shape))
            frame.to_csv(f, header=None, index=False)
finally:
    # Close all tile files.
    for f, _ in tile_files:
        f.close()
```

Comment: There's one issue still: the row selection condition (`(chunk["x"] >= current_tile_extent[0]) & ... & ... & ...`) does not include the upper bounds for `x` and `y` for tiles where `i` or `j` is maximal. So data points with `x == max_x` or `y == max_y` would not be included if those max values were an exact multiple of `tile_size`. The easiest solution would be to increment `max_x` and `max_y`, but depending on how large they are, adding 1.0 might underflow, and multiplying by 1.0001 wouldn't work for non-positive numbers and infinity.

Comment: Wow, complete code. I did not expect that, thank you very much. Now I was thinking about reading in chunks but it turned out my pc was able to read the files even without chunks, Still safer to do that in chunks anyway in case some files are too big. What I do not understand though does this code mean that all my 100GB  to 1TB data will be loaded into memory at once? I am afraid to try :)

Comment: Also in my code for clip of XYZ I use for every tile extent actually extended area by one fifth to make sure interpolation method I use at this moment (triangulation) will cover the whole original tile extent so no worries about x == max_x or y == max_y. Thank you.

Comment: You're welcome. No, your data won't be loaded at once; this code uses chunking. See how `get_df_in_chunks()` is used when finding min/max as well as when writing tile files?

Comment: I updated the code to only read all files twice. Was an easy change, actually. -- Still, you can get faster by compressing the output and input files. And don't forget to tweak `chunksize`!

Comment: This approach is perfect. Before you adjusted the answer the idea came to my head too that the best will be to read files twice and in second go split into tiles. Thank you very much again.